# Oracle 11g Materialized View hangs

Tags: performance, oracle, view, freeze, materialized

I'm attempting to create a materialized view within Oracle using a pre-built view.

```
  create materialized view bfb_rpt_sch01.mvw_base_sales
  as select * from bfb_rpt_sch01.vw_base_sales;
```

This command will not execute and hangs.  I figured perhaps this has something to do with the view not being properly written. So I performed the following query on the view.

```
  select count(*) from bfb_rpt_sch01.vw_base_sales
```

This query takes about 6 minutes to execute and returns 2.7 million. This tells me the view is not the issue, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Define "hang".  Are you sure that the `CREATE` statement isn't just taking more time than you were hoping to fully materialize the result?  Copying data, generating `UNDO` and `REDO`, etc. may not be quick.  A `COUNT(*)` is pretty easy to optimize in a lot of cases since all Oracle has to do is an index scan on a primary key and since Oracle doesn't have to do things like compute functions that are applied to the projection.

Comment: Well, currently we're at 35 minutes in counting. Is there perhaps another way I can validate that it's generating the materialized view? Also, the view is actually 6 subqueries that are being union all together. I don't believe a index is being used when it counts the number of rows, but I could be wrong. The initial reason i'm creating this view is so I can create an index against the MVW to help speed up my queries.

Comment: Do you see the session clocking time on the database?  What do the waits look like?  Is it primarily I/O bound?  How much data does 2.7 million rows represent in MB/ GB?  How long does it take if you `SELECT * FROM view_name` and fetch all 2.7 million rows to your local machine?  What are the query plans for the `CREATE` statement vs. the `SELECT`?  Is this something that you are going to be doing a full refresh on regularly?  Or will you be incrementally refreshing (in which case a longer initial load may be perfectly acceptable)?

Comment: So I get the feeling my explain plan only used one subquery in the view, but nevertheless I've posted some stats below. I'm not quite sure what to look at here.session logical reads 250777
consistent gets 224273
no work - consistent read gets 223965
physical reads 222506
consistent gets direct 222273
physical reads direct 222273
db block gets 26504
db block gets direct 26082
physical read IO requests 13982
physical read total IO requests 13982
Number of read IOs issued 13965
Effective IO time 13082444
physical write IO requests 816
physical write total IO requests 816

Comment: Also, the entire exported file is 252,725KB. This took about 13 minutes to finish. The explain plan shows thats its typically used full table scans for nearly all the joins. I'm not sure if this is enough information for you, just let me know if i'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure out my issue. My (CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW AS) was using a different explain compared to my (CREATE TABLE AS). If my code contained the follow line of code, it would run completely fine as (CREATE TABLE AS), but it would continue to hang for 48+ hrs before it would fail when using (CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW AS).

```
WHERE a.column_name NOT IN (SELECT b.column_name FROM B) --culprit
```

I changed the code using the following and it now works fine.

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM B WHERE a.column_name = b.column_name) --works
```

I'm not sure why this happens, perhaps bug? I don't enough about ORACLE to make the call.

Comment: There's a chunk of the query optimizer that's turned off during mview creation (don't know why, but you'll find things in the Oracle support site for this). Same sort of trick helped me once, making sure the column selected in `not in (select ...)` are marked `not null` also sometimes helps.